# Moderator Review - How are we doing?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Since the start of my tenure here, I've been pretty proactive with closures and deletions, and most of my actions have generally been quite visible.

Now, while nobody's raised any serious complaints about what I do, I haven't had any other feedback either - and now I'd like to get some. So it's time to review this moderator.

How am I doing? Am I...

- enforcing policy correctly?
- closing the right things?
- deleting the right things?
- being helpful?

etc, etc. You get the picture. Any feedback, good or bad, on my actions is welcome.

Comment: Feedback on mine is also appreciated, although I'm far less active that Art here.

Comment: Same as Undo. Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll provide some feedback for each of you:

- ArtOfCode

I see your name on many closed questions. I agree with almost all of them, and those that I don't I believe I've provided feedback either in the question or on Meta. In all of those cases, you've provided good feedback.

You've also been active on Meta. This is important as it helps the community see problems that may not otherwise be visible. You've been involved in scope discussions, user education discussions and policy discussions. You've provided your input and even in the few instances where your input wasn't the most popular, you have followed the community's input.

- Undo

I see your name attached to closed questions as well. I have agreed with almost all of them. If I didn't, I've provided feedback.

I haven't seen you on Meta in a while though. Perhaps pop in and throw up an opinion once and a while.

- Adam

In all honesty, other than the recent NISC meta post, I can't recall the last time I saw some thing done by Adam. My assumption is that you aren't slacking off, because looking at your [recent actions](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/155/adam?tab=activity) I see you are doing reviews and tag wikis. I have no problems at all with these behind the scenes actions. Unfortunately, I can't provide much more feedback than that.

---

General feedback for all three

Keep talking to us. I've interacted with each of you on meta (some more recently than others). We're still a small site and community so you three are still the most visible users (versus mods on much larger sites).

I am happy with all of you as moderators.

Comment: My input: I'll be the first to admit the NISC post ordeal was an obvious error on my part. Also, based on what I've been seeing the past few weeks, my usual time of day I set aside for moderating here seems to be "after" that of Art's or Undo's, so I end up getting the tail end of the main mod tasks. So that's why I end up doing a lot of smaller things like tags and reviews.

Comment: @Adam I sure appreciate that; what I do often means I don't have time to go back and do those things :)